# Найдено несколько конфигурации конечной точки для этого контракта

Tags: c#

Всем доброго времени суток! Есть приложение серверная часть и клиентская. На серверной части есть сервис(служба) который генерирует Word документ вставляя данные в отмеченные места. А на клиентском стороне есть ссылка на службу. Который связывается с сервисом который на сервере. Из за какой то ошибки я должен был удалить ссылку на службу и обратно добавить но тут я уже получаю ниже показанную ошибку. Прошу добрых людей помочь. ))

[image: То что получаю как ошибку]

Сервис который генерирует docx ReportService

## Web.config

```
....
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_SessionService" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
      openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
      maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ReportService" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
      openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
      maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISMSSignService" />
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICardSuiteIssuingService" />
    <binding name="Automat Basic ServiceSoap">
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="Automat Basic ServiceSoap1" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
....
```

## configuration.svcinfo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configurationSnapshot xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-wcfconfigurationsnapshot">
  <behaviors />
  <bindings>
    <binding digest="System.ServiceModel.Configuration.BasicHttpBindingElement, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089:&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;utf-16&quot;?&gt;&lt;Data maxBufferSize=&quot;2147483647&quot; name=&quot;BasicHttpBinding_ReportService2&quot;&gt;&lt;security mode=&quot;None&quot; /&gt;&lt;/Data&gt;" bindingType="basicHttpBinding" name="BasicHttpBinding_ReportService2" />
  </bindings>
  <endpoints>
    <endpoint normalizedDigest="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;utf-16&quot;?&gt;&lt;Data address=&quot;../ReportService.svc&quot; binding=&quot;basicHttpBinding&quot; bindingConfiguration=&quot;BasicHttpBinding_ReportService2&quot; contract=&quot;ReportServiceReference.ReportService&quot; name=&quot;BasicHttpBinding_ReportService2&quot; /&gt;" digest="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;utf-16&quot;?&gt;&lt;Data address=&quot;../ReportService.svc&quot; binding=&quot;basicHttpBinding&quot; bindingConfiguration=&quot;BasicHttpBinding_ReportService2&quot; contract=&quot;ReportServiceReference.ReportService&quot; name=&quot;BasicHttpBinding_ReportService2&quot; /&gt;" contractName="ReportServiceReference.ReportService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ReportService2" />
  </endpoints>
</configurationSnapshot>
```

## ServiceReferences.ClientConfig

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ReportService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_SessionService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ReportService1" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ReportService2" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="../ReportService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ReportService" contract="ReportServiceReference.ReportService"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_ReportService" />
  <endpoint address="../SessionService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_SessionService" contract="SessionServiceReference.SessionService"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_SessionService" />
  <endpoint address="../ReportService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ReportService1" contract="ReportServiceReference.ReportService"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_ReportService1" />
  <endpoint address="../ReportService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ReportService2" contract="ReportServiceReference.ReportService"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_ReportService2" />
</client>
```

Comment: Код  конфигураций покажите же

Comment: Вы эти имеете ввиду?

Comment: Я подумал, может когда я удалил и обратно добавил, где-то старый остался прописанным и мешает... @Sv__t

Comment: Возможно. Покажите клиентскую конфигурацию: и раздел `bindings`, и раздел `client`.

Comment: Можно создать новый проект (решение) с нуля, добавить рефренс на службу, посмотреть конфиг - сделать изменения в рабочем проекте.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov :) я так и сделал. А ошибку я так и не нашел.

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю у Вас должны быть только `ReportService` и `SessionService`. На клиенте в конфиге удалите ненужные `binding` и `endpoint`:

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ReportService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_SessionService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="../ReportService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ReportService" contract="ReportServiceReference.ReportService"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_ReportService" />
  <endpoint address="../SessionService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_SessionService" contract="SessionServiceReference.SessionService"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_SessionService" />
</client>
```

Comment: Сейчас попробую